# Why dirname is not a module atribute? (__ notation)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm studying the basics of node. According to the documentation, both `__dirname` and `__filename` belong to module scope. As expected, both:

```js
console.log(__dirname)
console.log(__filename)
```

Work, printing current dirname and filename.

But when i try calling them from `module`, only filename works:

```js
console.log(module.dirname)
console.log(module.filename)
```

The first one prints `undefined`.

1 - Why `console.log(module.dirname)` prints undefined?

2 - I'm confused about __notation. If it's not a sugar sintax for `module.`, what it is used for?

Comment: The `module` object is *not* the scope. There are no "scope objects" in JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those variables are defined as arguments to a function that is wrapped around your module code like this:

```
(function(exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {

    // Module code actually lives in here

});
```

This does several things:

1. It provides a scope for your module (the function scope of the wrapper function).  Any top level variables you declare in your module will actually be scoped to the module, not at the top, top scope.
2. It provides the values of `require`, `module`, `__filename` and `__dirname` as independent variables that are unique for each module and cannot be messed with  by other modules.

The properties of the module object (collected with `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(module)` are:

```
  'id',
  'exports',
  'parent',
  'filename',
  'loaded',
  'children',
  'paths'
```

> Why dirname is not a module attribute?

The "why" would have to go into the head of the designer and discussion at the time the module system was designed.  It's possible that a module object might be accessible by some other code and passing `__dirname` and `__filename` as arguments to the wrapper made it so that even something else who had access to your module object couldn't mess with `__dirname` and `__filename`.  Or, it could have just been done for shortcuts in typing.  Or, it could have just been a personal design choice.

> Why console.log(module.dirname) prints undefined?

Because `dirname` is not a property of the module object itself (I have no idea why).  Instead, `__dirname` is passed as the wrapper function argument.

> I'm confused about __notation. If it's not a sugar syntax for module., what it is used for?

Usually, the `_` or `__` prefix is just used to make sure it doesn't accidentally collide with any regular variable declaration in the code.  My guess is that the original designers of node.js envisioned existing code bases being used in modules and they wanted to lessen the chances of a variable naming collision.

---

Some of your question seems to be about why aren't all of these just properties of the module object.  I can think of no particular reason why that wouldn't have been a perfectly normal and logical design.

To save typing, there are object lots of references to `require` so I can certainly see an argument for not making us all type
`module.require('someModuleName')` every time.

And, `exports` is already a property of `module`.  For example, `module.exports === exports`.  Using it as `module.exports` does have some use because you can define a whole new object for the exports:

```
module.exports = {
    greeting: "hello",
    talk: function() {...}
};
```

But, you cannot do that by just reassigning the exports.  This will not work:

```
exports = {
    greeting: "hello",
    talk: function() {...}
};
```

So, I guess `exports` is also supplied as a shortcut when you just want to do:

```
exports.talk = function() {...}
```

But, module.exports is needed if you're assigning a whole new exports object.

Comment: That's something i also find kind of confusing. As far as I know, ```exports``` is a ```module``` object. ```require``` is a ```module``` method. And ```filename``` is a ```module``` attribute.  **Why** all of them are needed, since they're all usable via ```module.``` operator? It seems very redundant for me

Comment: @abcson - Yes, some of them are redundant, probably just for shortcut in typing.  For example, `module.exports === exports` by default.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help

const fs = require('fs');

**dirname** = fs.realpathSync('.');

Now, it's upon you what you are using '**dirname**' of 'dirname'

Comment: Please use [code formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).